# Редактирование JSON файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

У меня есть json файл где хранятся такого типа данные:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "respects": 1300,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 2,
        "respects": 500,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 3,
        "respects": 300,
        "rewards": 0
    }
]
```

И есть такой код:

```
import json

with open("stickmans.json", "r+") as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
    
    #Получаем респекты игроков
    stickmens = [i["respects"] for i in data]

    bet = 2000
    
    #Если ставка не перебивает минимальную сумму респекта.
    if bet < stickmens[-1]:
        print("FALSE")
        return

    for i, lot in enumerate(stickmens):
        #Если ставка игрока выше текущей
        if bet > lot:

            first = data[0]
            second = data[1]

            data[i]["user_id"] = 100
            data[i]["respects"] = bet
            data[i]["rewards"] = 0

            #Если игрок он перебил 1 или 2 место:
            if i in (0, 1):

                print(first)
                print(second)

                if i == 0:
                    print(first["respects"])
                    #Если игрок занимает первое место, переводим старого лидера на 2
                    data[1]["user_id"] = first["user_id"]
                    data[1]["respects"] = first["respects"]
                    data[1]["rewards"] = first["rewards"]

                print(second["respects"])
                #Переводим игрока который на 2 месте на 3
                data[2]["user_id"] = second["user_id"]
                data[2]["respects"] = second["respects"]
                data[2]["rewards"] = second["rewards"]

            break

    fh.seek(0)  # rewind
    json.dump(data, fh, indent=4)
    fh.truncate()
```

Я пытаюсь сделать, если какая-то ставка перебила уже существующую, то поменять позиции игроков в нашем случае 2000 перебиваем саму первую ставку 1300 она будет заменена, после чего первый игрок с 1300 будет переведен на 2 место, а игрок с 2 на 3 чтобы вышло так:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 100,
        "respects": 2000,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "respects": 1300,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 2,
        "respects": 500,
        "rewards": 0
    }
]
```

Но при выполнении кода все попросту дублируется, и выходит не то что нужно а все одинаковые значения:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 100,
        "respects": 2000,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 100,
        "respects": 2000,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 100,
        "respects": 2000,
        "rewards": 0
    }
]
```

Как можно это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве подсказки

```py
bets = [
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "respects": 1300,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 2,
        "respects": 500,
        "rewards": 0
    },
    {
        "user_id": 3,
        "respects": 300,
        "rewards": 0
    }
]


new_bet = {
    "user_id": 100,
    "respects": 2000,
    "rewards": 0
}

bets.append(
    new_bet
)

bets.sort(
    key=lambda x: x['respects'],
    reverse=True
)

print(bets[:3])
# [{'user_id': 100, 'respects': 2000, 'rewards': 0}, {'user_id': 1, 'respects': 1300, 'rewards': 0}, {'user_id': 2, 'respects': 500, 'rewards': 0}]
```